# How much pure water must be added to lower the concentration by 2%

Tags: exponential-function

The concentration of salt in a 6000-gallon sea world aquarium is a bit high at 4% salt. How much pure water must be added to lower the concentration by 2%?

What I tried:
I tried to draw this out and I believe that the equations are:

6000+x=y
.04+0=.02

I am having a hart time figuring out the equations.

Comment: Hint:  the amount of salt you have doesn't change when you add water.  Should say:  I'm not quite sure what it means to "lower the concentration by $2\%$.".  Do you mean that the final mix should be $2\%$ salt instead of $4\%$ salt?  That's a big change.

Comment: It appears that you are trying to lower the concentration *to* $2\%$ rather than *by* $2\%$.  I would think the new concentration should be $.98\cdot.04=3.92\%$.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @saulspatz the natural meaning of your question is a reduction to $3.92$%.

So you require

$$6000\times4=(6000+v)\times3.92$$
$v\approx 122.45$ gallons.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's work out how much of the water is currently salt - $6000 \cdot 4\% = 240$ gallons of salt.

Say we add $x$ gallons of pure water. The new total amount of water is $6000 + x$, so the proportion of salt is $240 / (6000 + x) = 2\%$ (or whatever percentage you decide is what you're aiming for, depending how you read the question. Could be $3.92\%$ `:)`). Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the right interpretation of the problem.  Please see my comment on the original post.